# IP5306 questions (battery management IP)

Tags: batteries, power-electronics, lithium-ion

I have some question about this IP
Datasheet link https://github.com/Xinyuan-LilyGO/LilyGo-T-Call-SIM800/blob/master/datasheet/IP5306%20REG%20V1.4.pdf

1. Is the lithium ion cell is embedded within the chip or external?
2. How does it charge the cell when needed?
3. How does it discharge it when needed? (high consumption peek)

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that most of the datasheet written in Chinese

Comment: Try this: http://www.datasheetcafe.com/ip5306-datasheet-battery-ic/